# Why response 304 doesn't have Content-Type header?

Tags: http, express, http-headers

I've been playing with express.js trying to return simple json object and noticed that even though I explicitly set `Content-Type` header to be `application/json` it is only visible on first response when status code is 200. Every following response with 304 won't have `Content-Type` header.

My code sample:

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    res.send([
        { user: "john", email: "john@example.com"},
        { user: "marry", email: "marry@example.com"},
        { user: "dan", email: "dan@example.com"}
    ]);
});
```

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`304 Not Modified` means that the request contained a [conditional header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3) asking the server to respond with the contents of the resource *only if* the the resource has been modified.

Since no content is being returned, the `Content-Type` header is not sent. This is [the recommended behavior](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1) for a `304 Not Modified` HTTP reply.

From [RFC 7232 §4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1) :

> The server generating a `304` response **MUST** generate any of the
> following header fields that would have been sent in a `200 (OK)`
> response to the same request: `Cache-Control`, `Content-Location`, `Date`,
> `ETag`, `Expires`, and `Vary`.
>
> Since the goal of a `304` response is to minimize information transfer
> when the recipient already has one or more cached representations,
> a    sender **SHOULD NOT** generate representation metadata other than the
> above listed fields unless said metadata exists for the purpose of
> guiding cache updates (e.g., `Last-Modified` might be useful if the
> response does not have an `ETag` field).

I don't know anything about express.js, but it I would look into what sort of caching is being done.